# Fail to install package Facebook in CMD

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, cmd, windows-10

When I type pip3 install --user Facebook in my CMD. Output appear as below

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement facebook (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for facebook

Comment: Which one of these packages are you trying to install? https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=facebook&submit=search

Comment: I am trying below in pycharm
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token, version ='2.11')

Comment: What happens if you use `pip3 install FacebookGraph`? First, you might want to update `pip` using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Also, I do not find a `--user` parameter for pip.

Comment: Please do us a favor and tell what the fix was.

Answer (score 0):

I just face this same issue. I solved by installing facebook-sdk instead just facebook.
Run :-  **pip install facebook-sdk** or  **pip3 install facebook-sdk**